# In 3-dimensional space, what is the set of all points 12 units from the origin?

Tags: geometry, 3d, coordinate-systems

I have come across this question in an ACT practice paper, Form 0057B. The only search result I can find is an explanation on a website called crackacc, but it has become a broken link. The options are: a circle, a sphere, a line, a cylinder, and 2 parallel lines. My answer was a cylinder, but I got wrong and I have been trying to visualize what the resulting shape would be but I cannot come to a solution.

Comment: It cant be a cylinder.  The points that lie in the cross-section of a plane are all equidistance from the origin but the point that lie above the plane will be equidistance from a point *above* the origin.  To get to the origin would be further.  For instance.  If the point $(a,b,0)$ has a distance of $12$ from $(0,0,0)$ then $(a,b,5)$ will have a distance of $12$ from $(0,0,5)$ and the distance from $(a,b,5)$ to $(0,0,0)$ will be $\sqrt{12^2 + 5^2} = 13 \ne 12$.

Comment: Imagine you had a pet humming bird on a leash and she wanted to fly as fare in any direction she can and the leash does *not* extend.  How for above you can she go and how far at an angle can she go.  What shape is that? .....  I'm not sure how you were supposed to answer except by intuition, but this *is* intuition it is reasonable to expect everyone to have.... Anyway what ever shape it is it will, by symmetry, be the same of you view it from its side.

Comment: Every point on the surface of the sphere is at the equal distance of its centre (we call this distance the *radius* of the sphere). So we are talking about a sphere with radius $12$ units, centered in the origin.

Answer (score 0):

It is a sphere. If you know that in two dimensions that it would have been a circle, then you can reason as follows. Imagine looking at the object from the side, or from above, and what would you see? A circle. From any direction you would see a circle. And the things that are circles from every direction are spheres.

Comment: Oh wow.. I didn't know about the "all things that are circles from every direction are spheres". I'll take this approach next time I encounter a 3D question, thank you!

Comment: Well, it’s not quite that simple, as you can make things that aren’t spheres,  but which do look like circles from all sides (I think), but they aren’t simple shapes, definitely not in the list of choices you had.

Comment: Oh I see... thank you for elaborating :-)

Answer (score 0):

Aaron's answer is good but I wish to add two elaborations (I don't have much history here so I can't leave a comment).

First, let's speak directly to "I have been trying to visualize what the resulting shape would be". Preamble: Bang a nail into a piece of paper on a wood board. Tie one end of a 12 cm string to nail, other end to a pen. Drawing on the paper with the string taut you get a familiar shape, right? Now, instead of a nail on a board, tie the string to the top of a flagpole; keeping the string taut, try to make the free end visit every allowed position, "drawing" invisibly in the air; what shape is that?

Second, the allowed answers in the test question bother me. *Sphere* almost always refers to a solid 3-d object, which includes (infinitely) many points closer to the origin. The correct name of the shape we are discussing is *spherical shell*. (You may have wrongly remembered or reported the original wording; it's also possible that the people who make these tests are way less mathematically capable than those of fifty years ago.)

Comment: In mathematics, the sphere refers to the shell, and the solid object bounded by it is called a ball.

Comment: @Elliot Yu I can't speak to conventions of all branches of math but present topic is at highschool level, and I don't think you'll find a h/s math textbook saying the volume of a sphere is 0 (which is the volume of an ideal spherical shell).